# Changing the next input element value using jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working on a project using ASP.NET MVC and attempting to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget so that the user can select from a list of Exercise names and the jQuery code will automatically set the ExerciseId value based on the Exercise selected.

I have been using the method from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762959/jQuery-UI-Autocomplete-in-MVC-Selecting-Nested-Ent) and the autocomplete allows the selection from a list of Exercise names however I can't seem to set the value for the ExerciseId.

The HTML/Razor code from my view looks as follows:

```
<tbody id="tablebody">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExerciseRecords.Count; i++ )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseName, new { @class = "autocomplete form-control", id = "", data_url = @Url.Action("AutoComplete") })                
        </td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseId, new { id = "ExerciseId_" + i, name = "ExerciseId", @class = "ExerciseId"})
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Reps, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Reps", value = 0 })
            <input type="hidden" name="ExerciseRecord.Index" value=@i />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Sets, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Sets", value = 0 })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Weight, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Weight", value = 0 })
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

This renders as the following HTML code:

```
<tbody id="tablebody">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="autocomplete form-control" data-url="/Workout/AutoComplete" name="ExerciseRecords[0].Exercise.ExerciseName" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <input class="ExerciseId" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseId must be a number." data-val-required="The ExerciseId field is required." id="ExerciseId_0" name="ExerciseRecords[0].Exercise.ExerciseId" type="hidden" value="" />
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Reps must be a number." data-val-required="The Reps field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Reps" type="text" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ExerciseRecord.Index" value=0 />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Sets must be a number." data-val-required="The Sets field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Sets" type="text" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Weight must be a number." data-val-required="The Weight field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Weight" type="text" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery code I have looks like:

```
var autoCompVals = {
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var url = $(this.element).data('url');

        $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function (data) {
            response(data)
        })
    },


    select: function (event, ui) {            
        $(event.target).next().val(ui.item.id);   
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(event.target).val('').next().val('');
        }
    }
};

$(".autocomplete").autocomplete(autoCompVals);
```

The JSON data for the exercises looks as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"value":"Bench Press","label":"Bench Press"},{"id":2,"value":"Deadlift","label":"Deadlift"},{"id":3,"value":"Chin-up","label":"Chin-up"},{"id":4,"value":"Squat","label":"Squat"},{"id":5,"value":"Overhead Press","label":"Overhead Press"},{"id":7,"value":"Dumbbell Curl","label":"Dumbbell Curl"}]
```

I've tried using next(), next('input[type=hidden]'), nextAll('input[type=hidden') but none of them seem to be changing the input value for the ExerciseId.

When I attempt to save, the ModelState is invalid and every value is as it was entered on my form, except for ExerciseId which has an attempted value of "".

Can anyone offer any advice as to what it is I'm doing incorrectly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer:

```
$(event.target).parent().next()
```

That is because `.next()` won't step outside of it current nesting level.  You have to go back up to the td, then get the next child (of td's parent, which is the tr).  However...

Better answer:
Don't put input elements directly inside a tr element.  It's not valid.  Here's an example, where I moved the hidden element inside the td with the autocomplete and changed it to type text (Change it back to hidden to keep it hidden):

```js
var autoCompVals = {
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
        var url = $(this.element).data('url');
      
        /* Simulate call */
        response([{"id":1,"value":"Bench Press","label":"Bench Press"},{"id":2,"value":"Deadlift","label":"Deadlift"},{"id":3,"value":"Chin-up","label":"Chin-up"},{"id":4,"value":"Squat","label":"Squat"},{"id":5,"value":"Overhead Press","label":"Overhead Press"},{"id":7,"value":"Dumbbell Curl","label":"Dumbbell Curl"}]);
        return;

        $.getJSON(url, { term: request.term }, function (data) {
            response(data)
        })
    },


    select: function (event, ui) {            
        $(event.target).next().val(ui.item.id);   
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            $(event.target).val('').next().val('');
        }
    }
};

$(".autocomplete").autocomplete(autoCompVals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="tablebody">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="autocomplete form-control" data-url="/Workout/AutoComplete" name="ExerciseRecords[0].Exercise.ExerciseName" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="ExerciseId" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExerciseId must be a number." data-val-required="The ExerciseId field is required." id="ExerciseId_0" name="ExerciseRecords[0].Exercise.ExerciseId" type="text" value="" />      
    </td>

    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Reps must be a number." data-val-required="The Reps field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Reps" type="text" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ExerciseRecord.Index" value=0 />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Sets must be a number." data-val-required="The Sets field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Sets" type="text" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Weight must be a number." data-val-required="The Weight field is required." name="ExerciseRecords[0].Weight" type="text" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

The corrected razor view:

```
<tbody id="tablebody">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ExerciseRecords.Count; i++ )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden("ExerciseRecord.Index",i)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseName, new { @class = "autocomplete form-control", id = "", data_url = @Url.Action("AutoComplete") })  
            @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseId, new { id="ExerciseId_"+i, name="ExerciseId", @class="ExerciseId"})              
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Reps, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Reps", value = 0 })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Sets, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Sets", value = 0 })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Weight, new { id = "", @class = "form-control", name = "Weight", value = 0 })
        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

I also moved the index to the top, where I believe it needs to be, and changed it to the Html.Hidden form instead of raw html just be consistent since you are using the Html Helpers for everything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot @robert. That works perfectly. I wonder if there is one additional thing you might be able to help with. I want to add an additional hidden id input within the same <td> element as the ExerciseId input. How would I change the value of this element? I've tried $(event.target).next().next() and $(event.target).nextAll().eq(1), but when I submit the form the ExericseId value has been changed but the next hidden input still has the value = "".

Comment: Both of those should have worked.  Are you sure you put it in the right td?

Comment: Yeah it was within the same td but it turns out I didn't need it after all so I won't spend any longer on why it wasn't working :) Thanks for all the help @robert